# I can't download the Terser library

Tags: javascript, webpack

For reasons of version incompatibility, the UglifyJs library is not supporting ES6, so I am trying to install the Terser library in webpack and the following error occurs:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: capitulo-webpack@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"4.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.1.0" from terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.10
npm ERR! node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev terser-webpack-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried to install it in the terminal with the command npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev, but I got an error, I expected the library to be downloaded normally

Comment: You've not provided enough information for someone to reproduce the problem.  Your issue likely lies with mutual incompatibility with your other dependencies.